# ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error

Tags: ntfs, input, xubuntu, badblocks

xubuntu, NTFS.
When I trying to open directory with files:

```
username@username-hp:/media/username/dir1/dir2/music$ la
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

Also if I open the directory with the thunar, there is empty inside, but if I open the directory by console it works:

```
username@username-hp:/media/username/dir1/dir2/music$ cd KORN
username@username-hp:/media/username/dir1/dir2/music/KORN$ ls -alhis
total 92K
12484 4,0K drwxrwxrwx 1 username username 4,0K jan 29  2013 .
 7386  88K drwxrwxrwx 1 username username  88K jan  7 17:53 ..
12485    0 drwxrwxrwx 1 username username    0 jan 29  2013 1994 - Korn
```

I have access almost to all files in the directory. For example torrent and media player programs have a troubles of several files in the 'music' directory and I can't access to these files from console:

```
username@username-hp:/media/username/dir1/dir2/music$ cd InternalDirectory
bash: cd: InternalDirectory: No such file or directory
```

Aaaaa, help!

Comment: Is this a local or remote filesystem?  How is it mounted?  Do you have any interesting (and relevant) logs?

Comment: It is remote file system, plugged by usb (case for hdd). I don't have any logs. Or I don't know where it is.

Comment: In addition, when I create a file via file manager it immediately disappears  but it exists (I can open it if I know the pathway or open the directory), also if I touch file by console it dosn't disappears and works normal but if I close the file manager and open it again - created file does't visible already but is still exist in the directory. I also checked out entire hdd on bad blocks in read mode - zero errors.

Answer (score -1):

Do a `chkdsk /F` from a Windows machine.

Comment: When I plug in the device to the windows machine it immediately cause the error, something like "the disk can't be mount, do you want to format disk?" The disk contains more important data so I scare about windows methods of solving. As I understood for now, the problem in partition table (it seems broken when I had hard restart). But it usable (with some errors) for Ubuntu. I still looking for appropriate program or methods to fix that.